# NSNumberFormatter SpellOutStyle with "and"

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

Is there an NSNumberFormatter similar to SpellOutStyle with "and"
I'm trying to solve Project Euler #17 which requires writing out numbers with "and"

For example, 556 would be five hundred and fifty-six

Using NSNumberFormatter, I have the following code

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.SpellOutStyle
let number = formatter.stringFromNumber(556)!
print(number) //prints five hundred fifty-six
```

NSNumberFormatterStyle.SpellOutStyle is not listing the "and". 
Is there a different method I can use to print the "and"?

Comment: The use of `and` between `five hundred` and `fifty-six` is not proper grammar.

Comment: @rmaddy but that's what the problem domain wants me to print.             "NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage."

Comment: It's more in the spirit of project Euler to implement it without using a built-in library function.

Comment: If that's correct for British, you could try to see if changing the locale property of the formatter will help (but I still think you should implement this without a number formatter)

Comment: @LouFranco aww I thought there was an easier way. How about using extensions to add a functionality that adds "and" in the number string?

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to learn how to do and what you hope to get out of doing them.  If it's "explore iOS libraries", then this is fine.  I think of project Euler as "practice algorithmic coding" (just my opinion -- do whatever interests you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"five hundred and fifty-six" is proper English to my ears. However, there's no locale in which `NSNumberFormatter` will give you back that result. You can roll your own by subclassing `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
class MyNumberFormatter: NSNumberFormatter {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.numberStyle = .SpellOutStyle
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func stringFromNumber(number: NSNumber) -> String? {
        // Make sure the number is an integer. Otherwise use NSNumberFormatter default formatting
        guard ceil(number.doubleValue) == floor(number.doubleValue) else {
            return super.stringFromNumber(number)
        }

        switch (number.integerValue - (number.integerValue % 100), abs(number.integerValue % 100)) {
        case let (bigUnit, smallUnit) where abs(bigUnit) >= 100 && 0 < smallUnit && smallUnit < 100:
            return super.stringFromNumber(bigUnit)! + " and " + super.stringFromNumber(smallUnit)!
        default:
            return super.stringFromNumber(number)
        }
    }
}

// Usage:
let formatter = MyNumberFormatter()
print(formatter.stringFromNumber(556)!)
```

Obviously, this only works for integers and English locales.